# How to change email settings in django dynamically

Tags: django, django-email

I want to make an email sender app that took user email and password and send an email to multiple recipients. I am not sure whether it is possible to do because we have to provide Email_HOST_USER in settings. If anyone can help me with explanation please?

Answer (score 1):

The `EMAIL_HOST_USER` setting is just a default value.

See the [docs for send_mail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail), it accepts an `auth_user` argument:

***auth_user:** The optional username to use to authenticate to the SMTP server. If this isn’t provided, Django will use the value of the EMAIL_HOST_USER setting.*

Same goes for `auth_password`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Le Minaw

Comment: No problem. It's good practise to [mark your question an answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).